# Spectra of undirected $d$-regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a undirected $d$-regular graph, that is, a graph whose all vertices have the same degree $d$. It is known that the eigenvalues $\sigma_i$, $i=1,\cdots,n$, of the adjacency matrix are real and they satisfy
$$
d = \sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2\geq\cdots\geq\sigma_n\geq-d.
$$
Moreover, if $G$ is a bipartite graph then $\sigma_n = -d$.

My question is: Does the opposite holds, that is, if $\sigma_n = -d$ then $G$ is bipartite? If not, what would be the counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not true. Take the disjoint union of a $d$-regular graph and a non-bipartite $d$-regular graph.  You obtain a graph that is not bipartite and clearly the least eigenvalue is $-d$.

What is true however is that a graph is bipartite iff its spectrum is symmetric over 0.

Comment: It is also true that if $G$ is $d$-regular and _connected_, and $-d$ is an eigenvalue then $G$ is bipartite.